# Need to programmatically create amazon Lambda schedule triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to be able to programmatically create amazon lambda schedule triggers. Like to execute a function every five minutes. I can easily do it with a console, but I need many in different environments, so I need to do it in a script. Java or python or even a cli call will do.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon CloudWatch Events to achieve it.
Take a look at AWS Lambda documentation. These pages show you how to trigger a Lambda function on a schedule:

[Using AWS Lambda with Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)

[Run an AWS Lambda Function on a Schedule Using the AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

You can use [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awscli) package in Python to run AWS CLI commands.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.